# Change Size of Javascript Background Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Javascript that randomly picks a new background image.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function changeImg(imgNumber)   {
        var myImages = ["images/001.jpg", "images/002.jpg", "images/003.jpg",      "images/004.jpg"]; 
        var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
        var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
        document.body.style.backgroundImage =      'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
    }
    window.onload=changeImg;
    </script>
```

I want to know how to resize that image. 
Also, I want to know how to make the image not stay fixed to the page, but scroll along with the page normally.

Comment: can you post the code you are working on ?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge you can't resize background images in body using css. but you can achive same senario following below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .bgimage{
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                z-index:-1;
                width:500px;
                height:200px;
            }
            .content{
                position:relative;
                z-index:1;
            }
            p{
                color:#fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="bgimage" src="http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Download-Hulk-HD-Wallpaper-For-Computer.jpg" />
        <div class="content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis condimentum vestibulum elementum. Nunc cursus sem et odio porttitor bibendum. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus egestas sodales sapien, ut ullamcorper metus aliquam ac. Sed tellus ipsum, mattis nec vulputate non, ultrices vel mi. Etiam sodales porta nibh, dignissim porta eros viverra in. Nullam non augue lacus. Nullam et neque a arcu pellentesque mattis quis semper lectus. Ut a urna velit. Integer elementum, eros eu ullamcorper pretium, nisl est congue nibh, in aliquam risus massa nec lacus. Praesent blandit felis massa, ut suscipit lacus. Pellentesque sodales nulla at enim lobortis egestas ac ac urna. Pellentesque varius, erat ut mattis sodales, augue nisi luctus nibh, id ultrices lectus lectus feugiat mauris.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

if you want more details let me know...

Comment: Not sure how that helps me... I want to resize the CSS background image while the javascript I posted, changes that image every refresh.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I have to change background-size in my CSS body{

Comment: OK, I'm sorry I forgot to tell you that. You can't change the background image size using CSS2. But in CSS3 using `background-size` you can change the size. In my solution what I want to show you is you can use a seperate `img` tag and in your code rather than changing body background image you can change the `img` tag src attribute and give a width and height as you wish...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using media queries in CSS3 or little bit of coding with jQuery.
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Hope this may help you